# ContentChild by extended abstract class

Tags: angular, children

I have two different components that extend a common one.

```
AComponent extends BaseComponent {}
BComponent extends BaseComponent {}
```

There is a third component that has ng-content.

```
<wrapper>
  <a-component></a-component>
  <b-component></b-component>
</wrapper>
```

Unfortunately those component aren't visible in below scenario.

```
WrapperComponent {
  @ContentChildren(BaseComponent) components;
}
```

I don't want to create ContentChild with specific types (Acomponent, BComponnet).

Comment: Could you provide a repro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [Alias providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#alias-providers-useexisting) as a workaround.

Define your components as follows;

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'a-component',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: BaseComponent, useExisting: AComponent }]
})
export class AComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("a created.");
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'b-component',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: BaseComponent, useExisting: BComponent }]
})
export class BComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("b created.");
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

where `BaseComponent` is

```js
export abstract class BaseComponent {}
```

use it in the `WrapperComponent` as follows

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper',
  templateUrl: './wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wrapper.component.css']
})
export class WrapperComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(BaseComponent) components;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("components: ", this.components.length);
  }
}
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynqhwj

Comment: This meets my expectations. Sadly I have to provide the same chunk of code inside each A, B, C, ..., Z classes but still it does work. Thank you

Comment: Thanks heaps! It works perfectly. In my case, I need to have `@Output()` in my base class, so I also need to add `@Component()` tag for the base component.